# Chartboost sample app not showing Ads

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, objective-c

I am trying to integrate a tool Chartboost into our game.

We are using following tools for development.

1. Xcode 5.0.2.
2. Latest ChartBoost Library.
3. Deployment target being iOS 6.1.
4. Base SDK being iOS 7.0.
5. Game Engine Cocos2d-x ( C++ ).

In order to use ChartBoost I followed these steps.

1. Created an account at Chartboost.
2. Added an app

   - Platform: iOS
   - Nick Name: Added
     -Test Mode: Enabled

   and Its showing the App Id and App signature.
3. Added a Campaign.

   -Its On.

   -CampaignStart and End are blank, so it will be effective as soon as possible.

   -Filter By Bundle verion is Min 1.0 and Max blank .(already tried by keeping both blank.)

   -Selected the App I added ,as the app where this campaign will run.

   -Campaign Logic: Added test device with UUID.

   -Rest of the options are untouched.

For test purpose I downloaded and used the sample iOS project provided at ChartBoost site. I replaced the App Id and App signature with my App's ID and Signature.On running the app, it does not display any ads. It logs messages like :

-failure to load interstitial at location Default

-failure to load interstitial at location Pause screen

-failure to load more apps

-failure to load interstitial at location After level 1

I am not able to conclude what wrong I have done! Please help on this issue.

PS:
1. I have already received a mail from ChartBoost mentioning I have successfully integrated the SDK, and in front of added app , the SDK and Frame icons are lit(green), which essentially shows , I have integrated the SDK correctly.

2.Our game  is still under development and as we are using the Cocos2d-x which is c++ Game engine ,so we will be using some wrapper to call the ChartBoost library. Once we get the idea how it works on native platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Chartboost sometimes it happens that you have set in the Chartboost dashboard that your game is in "Landscape" mode for example.
While your game is actually running in portrait mode.

In such cases you will get these errors.

Make both these same. Either change in the Chartboost dashboard for your app or change in the game's project file :)